# Debug in Qt show not acessible

Tags: c++, qt, debugging, gdb

Im using QT on ubuntu with gcc.
and can debug a class if the size is more than 65536, it shows not acessible.

this is the calss:

MyClass.h

```
class MyClass {
    int x[16384];
}
```

main.cpp

```
#include "MyClass.h"

int main() {

    MyClass* m = new Myclass;
    return 0;
}
```

when I debug it shows correctly, once i will change the size from 16384 to 16385 it shows "not acessible".

note that 16384*4(int) = 65536 (2^ 16).

how to fix it??

Comment: Why not use _heap_ memory for such large array?

Comment: It is actually on the heap as part of class object anyway.

Comment: That looks like an answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24739414/show-arrays-content-in-a-range-in-qt-debugger Time to close the question?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Show Array's Content in a Range in Qt Debugger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24739414/show-arrays-content-in-a-range-in-qt-debugger)